# Testing a simple PayPal "Buy Now" button - but why are there two different PayPal "looks"?

Tags: paypal

Just testing a simple single product "Buy Now" button in PayPal and finding that when clicking through to PayPal, PayPal will opt to show either one or other of two different "flavours":

There's this look:
[image]

and then there's this look:
[image]

Sure, I'm familiar with both, having experienced them both as an end user, and assumed it was down to the merchant's options or his choice of PayPal configuration.

But testing - now as a merchant - I'm finding either one will show, as I say at random. Don't get me wrong, either flavour performs its job. It's just a bit unsettling.

Do I need to be concerned? And why does PayPal do this?

**Update:**
From a bit more digging around, I believe these PayPal's terminology for these two themes are ***Classic*** and ***Enhanced***. But I'm still no wiser as to when and where PayPal opts to show one or the other.

Comment: Is the first one because you're logged into PayPal already on another browser tab?

Comment: @paulmorriss i didn't think so, but just to be sure, i double checked. logged out of paypal. just the same, i get the two flavours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they are doing [A/B Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing). This [blog article](http://www.getelastic.com/deconstructing-paypals-radical-checkout-redesign/) found that they were in 2010, so it looks very likely they are here too.